# Firefox loadedmetadata event

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, video

When I used the event handler:

video.on("loadedmetadata", function() {...})

Firefox does not seem to set the video dimensions properly when the callback is called. Chrome works perfectly fine. Is there a way to get the video dimensions correctly on firefox?

EDIT: 
It seems to work if I put a debugger and run through the code manually. That lead me to believe it's some sort of race condition. But that doesn't make sense to me since the method is being called which means the event should have properly occurred = dimensions should be set.

Here is a code snippet:

```
$("document").ready () ->
    # Setup variables
    video = $("#video")
    toolbar = $("#toolbar")
    canvas = $("#filter")
    context = canvas.get(0).getContext('2d')

    # Setup webcam
    # I have a separate webcam module that simply wraps the behavior of 
    # navigator.getMediaStream. Works fine in chrome.
    webcam.setup(() -> alert("Browser Unsupported."))
    webcam.getMedia({video:true}, (localMediaStream) ->
        video.attr("src", window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream))

        # Video loaded event
        video.on "loadedmetadata", (e) ->
            # Turn on video controls
            video.prop("controls", true)
            # Setup canvas dimensions and add border
            width = video.width()
            height = video.height()
            canvas
                .css("border", "solid")
                .css("border-width", "1px")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
            # In firefox, the width and height are 0! In chrome, they
            # are correct. I tested videoWidth/videoHeight and most other
            # variables. Does not work.
```

Comment: Post a more complete code snippet, and explain exactly what you're seeing. It's perfectly possible that you have some other error that we can't see.

Comment: Added a snippet with some commented explanations.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=926753

Found out. It is indeed a bug in Firefox. Darn. Hopefully this will be fixed before I publish what I'm working on. Don't really want to put hacks in to make things compatible.

Comment: As of Mar 2014, this is still an unresolved bug in Firefox.  Need a fix or workaround!

Answer (score 0):

Summary of solution:

bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=926753

Firefox bug, currently seems like it does not call video events properly if being used with a webcam. Most likely do to the video being "loaded" even though the camera has not properly initialized and set the proper dimensions, so everything is called with incorrect values.